# Win32 API call to change a combobox selection

Tags: ms-access, winapi, vba

I am calling an external application from MS Access in Vb6 and trying to change a combo box selection, but all the sendmessage constants I have tried do not work. Code I have so far successfully opens the App, navigates to the correct window, expands the combobox and thats as far as i get. I have also attached a link to the Spy ++ tree

```
Sub RunSailwaveUpdates()
Dim hwnd As Integer
Dim SortSelect As String
SortSelect = "Fleet"
hwnd = FindWindow(vbNullString, "Sailwave - 
C:\Users\Public\Documents\Sailwave\Results\Summer Points.blw")
start_doc = ShellExecute(0&, "open", " 
C:\Users\Public\Documents\Sailwave\Results\Summer Points.blw", 0, 0, 
SW_NORMAL)
If start_doc = 2 Then Exit Sub
If start_doc = 3 Then Exit Sub
Do
DoEvents
hwindow2 = FindWindow(vbNullString, "Sailwave - 
C:\Users\Public\Documents\Sailwave\Results\Summer Points.blw")
hwindow3 = FindWindowEx(hwindow2, ByVal 0&, "ClaChildClient", vbNullString)
scoreseriesbutton = FindWindowEx(hwindow3, 0&, "ClaButton_0400000H", "Score 
Series")
Loop Until hwindow2 > 0 And hwindow3 > 0 And scoreseriesbutton > 0
WaitSeconds (0.5)
Call SendMessage(scoreseriesbutton, BM_CLICK, 0, ByVal 0&)
Do
DoEvents
scoreseries = FindWindow(vbNullString, "Score Series")
scoreseries2 = FindWindowEx(scoreseries, 0&, "ClaChildClient", vbNullString)
groupoption = FindWindowEx(scoreseries2, 0&, "ClaRadio_0400000H", "Score 
groups of competitors separately  -  scoring system is applied to each 
group")
groupfield = FindWindowEx(scoreseries2, 0&, "ClaPrompt_0400000H", "Grouping 
field")
groupfield1 = FindWindowEx(scoreseries2, ByVal 0&, "ClaDrop_0400000H", " ")
groupfield3 = GetWindow(groupfield, GW_HWNDNEXT)
Loop Until scoreseries > 0 And groupoption > 0 And groupfield > 0 And 
groupfield1 > 0 And scoreseries2 > 0 And groupfield1 > 0 And groupfield3 > 0
WaitSeconds (0.5)
Call SendMessage(groupoption, BM_CLICK, 0, ByVal 0&)
Do
DoEvents
Call SendMessage(groupfield3, CB_SHOWDROPDOWN, 1, 0)
Call SendMessage(groupfield3, CB_SETCURSEL, 2, 0)
Call SendMessage(groupfield3, WM_SETREDRAW, 1, 0)
selectedsort = SendMessage(groupfield3, CB_GETCURSEL, 0, 0)
Loop Until selectedsort > 0
End Sub
```

[Spy++ Extract](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1gcdp.png)

Comment: Isn't UIAutomation the way to do this?

Comment: Perhaps, but i need to pass variables from my application depending on front end user preferences

Comment: Yes. Still, UIAutomation is the system library that allows one to automate another program. There are literally thousands of questions on this site where people try to fake it using messages and struggle. It's a self-perpetuating nightmare. Each new person that tries to do this things sending messages is the solution, because websearch finds countless posts where people try to do it that way.

Comment: Have you tried to send a CBN_SELCHANGE notification through WM_MESSAGE juste after sending CB_SETCURSEL?

Comment: ok, just as i was getting to grips with messaging, looks like i need to re learn :-)

Comment: @jaudo: That won't work. `CBN_SELCHANGE` is posted by the implementation *in response to a selection change*. Sending it yourself will have no effect (other than running a potential handler at a random, unexpected time).